# Database, Using json field instead of ManyToManyField?

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose reviews can have zero or more tags.

One could implement this using three tables, `Review/Tag/ReviewTagRelation`.
ReviewTagRelation would have foreign key to Review and Tag table.

Or using two tables `Review/Tag`. Review has a json field to hold the list of tag ids.

Traditional approach seems to be the one using the three tables.
I wonder if it is ok to use the two tables approach when there's no need to reference reviews from tags.

i.e. I only need to know what tags are associated with a given review.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is always best to keep the data in your database normalized, unless there is a clean and clear cut reason for not doing so that makes sense as per your business requirements.

With normalized data, you know that no matter what, you will always be able to write a query to receive exactly what you are looking for, and if for some reason you want to return data as json, you can do so in your select query.